# jqPlot - Horizontal legend

Tags: jquery, css, jqplot

jqPlot has the ability to create a legend for a chart.  The examples show only vertical legends.  I would like to make a horizontal legend.  For instance, I want:

```
X-Label1 X-Label2 X-Label3
```

And don't want:

```
X-Label1
X-Label2
X-Label3
```

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is very easy to achieve using the [EnhancedLegendRenderer plugin](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-enhancedLegendRenderer-js.html). Just include the plugin and use options similar to this.

```
legend:{
    renderer: $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer,
    show: true,
    rendererOptions: {
        numberRows: 1
    }
}
```

You just have to set the `numberRows` to 1, so the legend will be rendered with only 1 row.

Comment: Thanks GayashanNA,  Didn't realize I had a response.  I will check it out.

Comment: This not only gives you one row, It let you click the legend in case you have many series and hide them. AWESOME!